# Custom display template behavior on page refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am having an issue with my custom template when page is refreshed. My scenario is that I have multiple address records to be displayed, in which I opted to use custom templates so I won't have to use foreach() to display each record. Here's my custom template code:

```
@model Address

<div>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressLine)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AddressLine)
<br />
</div>
```

Let's say I have 2 address records for display. What's happening is that upon initial page load, it will display 2 records correctly but when page is refreshed, it will display the 2 records again in which now I end up with 4 records on screen. Subsequent page refreshes will display even more duplicates on the screen. My question is, do I need to handle that page refresh event? Or am I just doing something very obviously wrong here?

**UPDATE**

As requested here is my code for the View and the Action,

View:

```
@model Patient
<div id="editDetails">
@using(Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Patient"))
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Addresses)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
</div>
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    Patient patient = patientRepository.GetPatientData(id);
    if (patient != null)
    {
        patientData.GetOtherDetails(patient);
        return View(patient);
    }
    else
        return View();
}
```

Comment: can you show some more code - specifically the View that is using the template, and the action that is associated with the View.  I would suspect that the issue has nothing to do with the template as it looks fine.

Comment: I found the issue, my `GetOtherDetails` method was continually adding Address records to the patient object's Addresses collection instead of creating a new instance which resulted to my problem. You 're correct as it really didn't have anything to do with my custom template.